# Remove particular substrings

Tags: ruby, string

I have these strings:

```
"test 123"
"Test 123"
"Tes 234"
"T 123"
"abc 123"
```

I want to remove the strings `"test"`, `"Test"`, `"TEST"`, `"T"`. I want something like this:

```
"123"
"123"
"234"
"123"
"abc 123"
```

I tried this:

```
string.sub(/\s*[\w']+\s+/, "")
```

but it removes `"abc"`. Please guide me on how to solve this.

Comment: Is it literally only those four strings you want to remove?  What about "t"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do

```
string.gsub(/t|test/i,"").strip
```

EDIT:  if you want to remove "T", "Te", "Tes" or "Test", followed by a space, in any combination of upper/lower case, then do

```
string.gsub(/te?s?t?\s/i,"").strip
```

Comment: string = "Te 123" string.gsub(/t|test/i,"").strip gives o/p "e 123" so its wrong not working

Comment: You didn't specify that you wanted to remove "Te".  Please edit your question to be more clear about your requirements.

Comment: Person who had asked question had specified above earlier only

Comment: Oh i beg your pardon, i thought you were the questioner.

Comment: isn't `split` redundant here?

Comment: I'm not using `split`.  Do you mean `strip`?

Comment: Note that `/te?s?t?/` will also match `tet`, `tst`, `tt` and `ts`.

Comment: @Stefan that's true - if the poster ever replies to my comment about more specific requirements, i may update this to be more specific :)